# Displaying 1d array as rows and columns

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I have a 1d array which consists of names of brands and want to display it in a format where column size is fixed with "3" and row number is expanding as the array size grows. For example, if there are 11 brands in the array, I want to display it like this;

```
X X X
X X X
X X X
X X
```

Here is the nested for loop where I tried to implement the desired logic:

```
int brandCount = Model.CampainBrands.Count();
int colLength = brandCount < 3 ? brandCount : 3; // Toplam marka sayısının 3'ün altında olması durumunu güvenceye alır
int rowLength = brandCount / colLength + (brandCount % colLength != 0 ? 1 : 0);
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
{
    <div class="row">
    @for (int j = 0; j < colLength && counter < brandCount; j++, counter++)
    {   
        var item = Model.CampainBrands[counter];
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="@Url.Action("List","Campain",new {brandCode = item.Code})">
                <div class="card" style="width: 5rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="@item.ImageUrl" height="60px" width="60px" />
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">@item.Name</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    }
    </div>
}
```

Is there any way to improve this algorithm? Thanks.

Comment: How about [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: if its c# , then why cant you create a custom  type(class) with these three column names as properties. Then create a list with this type. Then it will be easy to do the task

Comment: you're lucky I didn't give you down thumbs for this! : P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 11).ToList();
const int rowlength = 3;

for (int i=0; i<numbers.Count; i=i+rowlength)
{
    Console.Write("<tr>");
    for (int j=i; j<numbers.Count && j<i+rowlength; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(numbers[j] + " ");    
    }
    Console.WriteLine("</tr>");
}
```

The outer loop ("i") loops through the list 3 at a time and is supposed to add "tr" tags around the row.

The inner loop ("j") uses the next 3 items of the list, unless there are not enough left. These will be the "td" items.

Comment: Did you try? you need an `&&` to prevent going beyond the total length (preventing index out of range) **and also** stop at (max) 3 items per row